# Transliteration schemes explained

Tags: discussion, transliteration

As far as I understand it, there are many ways of transliterating Hebrew for native English speakers.  Since Mi Yodeya is an English-based site, we use many different ones.  What are different transliteration schemes that are in use by regular contributors?

Please use the following template if possible:

```
Consonants: 

* א - (nothing) or '
* ב - V
* בּ - B
* ג - G
* גּ - G
* ד - D
* דּ - D
* ה - H (sometimes omitted)
* ו - V
* ז - Z
* ח - Ch or H
* ט - T
* י - Y
* כ - Kh or Ch
* כּ - Kh or Ch
* ל - L
* מ - M
* נ - N
* ס - S
* ע - (nothing) or '
* פ - F or Ph
* פּ - P
* צ - Tz or Ts
* ק - K or Q
* ר - R
* שׁ - Sh
* שׂ - S
* ת - T or S
* תּ - T

Vowels:

* ◌ָ - (kamatz) - a, ah, o, oh, aw
* ◌ֳ - (chataf kamatz) - a, ah, o, oh, aw
* ◌ַ - (patach) - a, ah
* ◌ֲ - (chataf patach) - a, ah
* ◌ֵ - (tserei) - e, eh, ei, ey
* ‏◌ֵ‏י  - (tserei malei) - e, eh, ei, ey
* ◌ֶ - (segol) - e, eh
* ◌ֱ - (chataf segol) - e, eh
* ◌ִ - (hirik) - i, ee
* ‏◌ִי‏ - (hirik malei) - i, ee
* ◌ֻ - (kubutz) - oo, u 
* וּ - (shuruk) - oo, u
* ◌ֹ - (holam chaser) - o, oh
* וֹ - (holam malei) - o, oh
* ◌ְ - (sh'va na) - eh, ah, e, ', i, (nothing), u, uh
* ◌ְ - (sh'va nach) - ' or (nothing)

Other notes:
(Fill in how you deal with meteg, dagesh, unusual emphasis, specialized Yiddish scheme,
prefixes or anything else that's particular to your transliteration method)
```

Comment: Closely related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1417 & http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1373.

Answer (score 2):

Consonants:

- א - (nothing) or '
- ב - V
- בּ - B
- ג - G
- גּ - G
- ד - D
- דּ - D
- ה - H (sometimes omitted)
- ו - V
- ז - Z
- ח - Ch or H
- ט - T
- י - Y
- כ - Kh or Ch
- כּ - Kh or Ch
- ל - L
- מ - M
- נ - N
- ס - S
- ע - (nothing) or '
- פ - F or Ph
- פּ - P
- צ - Tz or Ts
- ק - K or Q
- ר - R
- שׁ - Sh
- שׂ - S
- ת - T or S
- תּ - T

Vowels:

- ◌ָ - (kamatz) - a, ah, o, oh, aw
- ◌ֳ - (chataf kamatz) - a, ah, o, oh, aw
- ◌ַ - (patach) - a, ah
- ◌ֲ - (chataf patach) - a, ah
- ◌ֵ - (tserei) - e, eh, ei, ey
- ‏◌ֵ‏י  - (tserei malei) - e, eh, ei, ey
- ◌ֶ - (segol) - e, eh
- ◌ֱ - (chataf segol) - e, eh
- ◌ִ - (hirik) - i, ee
- ‏◌ִי‏ - (hirik malei) - i, ee
- ◌ֻ - (kubutz) - oo, u
- וּ - (shuruk) - oo, u
- ◌ֹ - (holam chaser) - o, oh
- וֹ - (holam malei) - o, oh
- ◌ְ - (sh'va na) - eh, ah, e, ', i, (nothing), u, uh
- ◌ְ - (sh'va nach) - ', (nothing)

Answer (score 2):

From http://web.archive.org/web/20080509063200/http://www.math.wustl.edu/~msh210/crusade/transliterate.html, my transliteration scheme:

> Consonants:
>
> - א - is not transcribed; however, see exceptions, below.
> - ב - v
> - בּ - b
> - ג - g
> - גּ - g
> - ד - d
> - דּ - d
> - ה - h. However, when it appears at the end of a word without any punctuation and without a dot in it, it is not transcribed.
> - ו - v
> - ז - z
> - ח - ch
> - ט - t
> - י - y. However, if it follows a chirik, tzere, or segol, and lacks punctuation, it is not transcribed. Also, if it follows a kamatz, lacks punctuation, and precedes a vav, it is not transcribed.
> - כ - ch
> - כּ - k
> - ל - l
> - מ - m
> - נ - n
> - ס - s
> - ע - is not transcribed; however, see exceptions, below.
> - פ - f
> - פּ - p
> - צ - tz
> - ק - k
> - ר - r
> - שׁ - sh
> - שׂ - s
> - ת - s
> - תּ - t
>
> Vowels:
>
> - ◌ָ - (kamatz gadol/rachav) - a
> - ◌ָ - (kamatz katan) - o
> - ◌ֳ - (chataf kamatz) - o
> - ◌ַ - (patach) - a
> - ◌ֲ - (chataf patach) - a
> - ◌ֵ - (tzere) - e
> - ◌ֶ - (segol) - e
> - ◌ֱ - (chataf segol) - e
> - ◌ִ - (chirik chaser) - i
> - ‏◌ִי‏ - (chirik male) - i
> - ◌ֻ - (kubutz) - u
> - וּ - (shuruk) - u
> - ◌ֹ - (cholam chaser) - o
> - וֹ - (cholam male) - o
> - ◌ְ - (sh'va na) - '
> - ◌ְ - (sh'va nach) - is not transcribed; however, see exceptions, below.
>
> Exceptions:
>
> - A sh'va nach is transcribed by an apostrophe when it occurs:
>
>   - before a vowelized alef or ayin;
>
>     after a sav, sin, or samach before a he; or
>
>     after a tes before a zayin
>
>   to avoid confusion.
> - Some words commonly transliterated differently than according to these rules are here transliterated in their usual way rather than by these rules.

And I generally italicize my transliterations.

Answer (score 1):

Consonants:

- א - a or a2
- ב - V
- בּ - B
- ג - gh
- גּ - j
- ד - D
- דּ - Dh
- ה - H hei with daggesh is h2
- ו - w
- ז - Z
- ח - ‎7
- ט - ‎6
- י - Y
- כ - Kh or Ch
- כּ - Kh or Ch
- ל - L
- מ - M
- נ - N
- ס - S
- ע - ‎3
- פ - F or Ph
- פּ - P
- צ - ‎9
- ק - Q or g most of the time its q
- ר - R
- שׁ - Sh
- שׂ - S
- ת - Th
- תּ - T

Vowels:

- ◌ָ - (kamatz) - aw
- ◌ֳ - (chataf kamatz) - aw
- ◌ַ - (patach) - ah
- ◌ֲ - (chataf patach) - ah
- ◌ֵ - (tserei) - ei
- ‏◌ֵ‏י  - (tserei malei) -  ei
- ◌ֶ - (segol) - ah
- ◌ֱ - (chataf segol) - ah
- ◌ִ - (hirik) -  ee will use i to save time and not elongate words
- ‏◌ִי‏ - (hirik malei) -  ee will use i to save time and not elongate words
- ◌ֻ - (kubutz) - oo, u
- וּ - (shuruk) - oo, u
- ◌ֹ - (holam chaser) - aw
- וֹ - (holam malei) - aw
- ◌ְ - (sh'va na) - ah
- ◌ְ - (sh'va nach) - ah